# Taylor series of an entire function which is not a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

I have an entire function which is not a polynomial. Is there a way to use the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem to prove there exists a point $z_0$ such that every coefficient of the Taylor series at $z_0$ is not zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of points where the $n$-th Taylor coefficient is zero is the set $D_n = \{w \in \mathbb{C}\,:\,f^{(n)}(w) = 0\}$. This is a closed discrete set, hence it is countable (because if it were not discrete the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) would imply that $f^{(n)} \equiv 0$, hence $f$ would be a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$). Thus, the set of points where at least one Taylor coefficient is zero is the countable set $D = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty D_n$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is uncountable, $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus D$ is non-empty.

Comment: At the moment I don't see an immediate way to answer your question using the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem.